# How can permanent ishwara create impermanent effects?

Tags: gods

How can a permanent being have temporary cognition due to the fact that objects and conditions are impermanent? How can a permanent being which is a permanent cause,create impermanent effects?

I am hindu but saw this buddhist argument and don't know how to respond.

thanks or any assistance

Comment: It is not clear what is the issue here. I will live for maybe 60-70 years. But I can create an effect like throwing a ball, which will last for a few seconds. If I can be a cause of the movement of the ball, why can't Ishwara be? My being the cause of the movement of the ball has nothing to do with whether I live for 10 years or 100 years or for eternity. Ask your Buddhist to clarify what his/her point is. Ask him/her what he/she means by a permanent cause.

Comment: I am not sure either what the issue is.

Comment: Because this permanent being can manifest in an not impermanant world and hence his actions are not impermanant.

Comment: The question itself is wrong. Only an impermanent cannot manifest permanent while permanent can manifest temporary. ex: Dreamer v dreaming. Dreamer goes about having 100 years while dream is brief 8hrs or 2hrs in sleep.

Comment: Argument itself is weak, a dreamer can create a dream/imagination but not the vice versa. A lie can be born from hiding truth not vice versa. A blind cant see the Sun even though it shines upon the whole earth.